# Cypress Codebuild Project Fails To Start

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress, e2e-testing

I have a codebuild cypress project that runs a buildspec file in order to run all of my cypress tests. I have recently updated to cypress v12 and node 16 and now when I run my codebuild project I get the following error:

```
/root/.cache/Cypress/12.0.0/Cypress/Cypress: error while loading shared libraries: libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory. 
Platform: linux-x64 (Amazon Linux - 2 (Karoo))
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I have tried a few things like:

```
yum install gtk3
```

but nothing is working.

Has anyone run into this with cypress v12?

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar issues with these libraries while running my Cypress tests in CodeBuild, in my case I added these lines in the install phase of the buildpsec file to solve it:

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y
sudo yum install -y chromium
```

Just ensure your instance type is of type Amazon Linux (I used 'aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:4.0')

Comment: It looks like they removed amazon-linux-extras from 5.0 image...